# How to limit the number of goroutines in recursion？

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm using goroutine to traverse all files in the specified directory. I want to know how to limit the number of goroutines under recursive traversal

I wrote this code, but it prompted panic chan send
`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var (
    wg    sync.WaitGroup
    // limit = make(chan bool, 20)
    // totalchan = make(chan bool)
)

func Work(path string, size int, finished bool) {
    fmt.Printf("gn1111: %d\n", runtime.NumGoroutine())

    defer func() { wg.Done() }()

    fl, err := os.ReadDir(path)
    if err == nil {
        for _, file := range fl {
            if file.IsDir() {
                // limit <- true
                wg.Add(1)
                go Work(path+file.Name()+"/", size, false)
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("gn2222: %d\n", runtime.NumGoroutine())
            }
        }
    }

    // if !finished {
    //  <-limit
    // }
}

func main() {
    
    path := "C:/Windows/"
    size := 0
    start := time.Now()
    wg.Add(1)
    go Work(path, size, true)
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("total= %d, cost: %v\n", 0, time.Since(start))
}
```

`

Comment: Use a [worker pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170852/is-this-an-idiomatic-worker-thread-pool-in-go/38172204#38172204) and just submit the tasks using a channel.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71766816/loop-through-all-files-in-all-folders-recursively-as-fast-as-possible-in-golang) you can find another example for this purpose.

Comment: Use a counting semaphore.

Answer (score 0):

the [errgroup](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup#Group.SetLimit) has a Limiting functionality

> SetLimit limits the number of active goroutines in this group to at most n. A negative value indicates no limit.
> Any subsequent call to the Go method will block until it can add an active goroutine without exceeding the configured limit.
> The limit must not be modified while any goroutines in the group are active.